# Access variables in other files without setting them as globals

Tags: php

I want to have one class that works with configuration settings. Configuration settings are stored inside `config/` directory where I want them to be separated to files. When I call my

```
Config::gi()->getConfig('config_name')
```

I want the Config class to be able to access the file `config/config_name.cfg.php` and return the array (from that file) named exactly the same.

This is because I don't want to read all the configuration data if it's not needed. Also, I'm a bit afraid that setting up configuration inside `$GLOBALS` variable wouldn't be the best solution. I thought about requiring or including those files and then returning their content, but it also seems a bit unprofessional.

What is the best practice to read the configuration like this? Thank you in advance.

For example: 
config/routes.cfg.php

```
$routes => [
    'index' => new Route([
        // route config here ...
    ])
];
```

and to get the routes array I would execute `Config::gi()->getConfig('routes');` from `helpers/Config.php` class.

Comment: Would this array always have the same name or different for each file?

Comment: yes, I'll add some code example to specify it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I would go this route, I would probably load all configs (most likely from a single file) into the class the first time and go from there.  Also you can look at [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) if you don't want to write out arrays when they change.  But for your case, simply:

```
public function getConfig($name) {
    if(file_exists("config/$name.cfg.php")) {
        include("config/$name.cfg.php");
        return ${$name}; //this translates to $routes in your example
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, the next logical question might be how to save the config when it changes:

```
public function setConfig($name, $data) {
    file_put_contents("config/$name.cfg.php", "$name = " . var_export($data, true) . ";");
}

$routes = array(/* with some stuff in it */);

Config::gi()->setConfig('routes', $routes);
```

Comment: Well, I'm at the beginning right now, so it'd be easy to change things around... Would it be better to load everything at once?

Comment: I would unless there is a MASSIVE amount and only small pieces will ever be used.

Comment: Alright, I might include them at once then. There shouldn't be a lot of data in there, but I might have a lot of config files. Hope it won't make any issues. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Also, added next logical question ;-)